# How would I make this more efficient? (python)

Tags: python, json

I just got my awnser to the question thank you to whoever awnsered it I really apriciate it!
https://github.com/sick2as/New-Coding-Tutorial

Comment: it seems to me like a perfectly valid and efficient python code, that works in the amount of time it is expected to work in, if speed is the main issue here then a data-oriented design could be a better approach, perhaps using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) to store students data in the files and read from them, and calculating those averages in bulk instead of per-student using pandas, there's room for improvement if speed is the main issue, but if it needs to look more pythonic, then some OOP with python dataclasses is a good improvement over dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reversed your code,

```
from imghdr import tests
import random
import time
import json
print("Disclaimer this is a fake person with fake grades no real person had grades recorded ")
print("also thank you for using my software By: PTSCODING")

names = ["james", "john", "joe", "Jason", "Mick", "Nina"]
classes = ['math', 'science', 'social studies', 'reading', 'grammar']

rd_1 = random.randint(0, 100) 
rd_2 = random.randint(70, 100)
student = {
    "name": names[random.randint(0, 2)],
    'tclass': [random.choice(classes)],
    "assignment": [rd_1] + [rd_2]*2,
    "test": [rd_2]*2,
    "participation": [rd_1]*3
}

def get_time():
    return time.localtime

def get_average(grade):
    return float(sum(grade)) / len(grade)

def calculate_total_average(students):
    assignment = get_average(students["assignment"])
    test = get_average(students["test"])
    return 0.1 * assignment + 0.7 * test + 0.2

def assign_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

def get_all_studinfo():
    print(
        f'Name: {student["name"]}  \n Class {student["tclass"]} \n Assignments: {student["assignment"]} \n Tests: {student["test"]} \n'
    )
    print(
        f"{student['name']}'s averages in every type of class is ",
        round(calculate_total_average(student)), "\n"
    )
    print(
        f"{student['name']}'s letter grade is ",
        assign_letter_grade((calculate_total_average(student))), "\n"
    )
    print(
        f"Now that you know {student['name']}'s grade you can now leave. \nHave a great day! :)")


js = {"Name": student['name'],
      "grades": calculate_total_average(student)}
with open("student.json", 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(js))


get_all_studinfo()
```

Things changed.

- `student` dictionary intialisation
- `get_average` functions
- `json.dumps` for the json file writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library called `refrub`, it is a tool for refurbishing and modenizing Python codebases. And see what can be optimized.

See : https://github.com/dosisod/refurb

Or see this article on Medium : https://medium.com/@fareedkhandev/make-your-python-code-more-elegant-readable-or-modern-with-one-command-eb910cefded3